# Can I use my Pasmo and/or Suica from Tokyo when traveling Fukuoka?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, japan, fukuoka

I have a couple of [Pasmo](http://www.pasmo.co.jp/en/) and [Suica](http://www.jreast.co.jp/e/pass/suica.html) stored-value travel smartcards purchased in Tokyo several years ago kicking around.  Can I use these on an upcoming trip to Fukuoka?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, you can.  On March 23, 2013, the ten largest transit smartcards in Japan became fully(*) compatible, and this includes Pasmo, Suica and all three systems used in and around Fukuoka: [Sugoca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugoca) (JR Kyushu), [Nimoca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimoca) (Nishitetsu) and [Hayakaken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayakaken) (Fukuoka City Subway).

[image]
(diagram [courtesy of JR East](http://www.jreast.co.jp/e/pass/suica.html#category03))

(*) For tickets, anyway, electronic money is a little more complicated, and there's a long tail of non-top-ten cards that are only partly compatible.  See [this diagram with oh-so-many arrows on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ICCard_Connection_en.svg) for the gruesome details.

Comment: Complicating the issue further is that some other cards are compatible with only some of the ten cards above. The most prominent example is the Paspy card, which is used by virtually all non-JR trasport operators in Hiroshima prefecture, and is compatible with Icoca only. (There are also some minor lines in and around Tokyo which accept Suica and Pasmo only.)

Comment: There's also a "expiration" of sorts, if the card is not used for five(?) years then the stored value is nullified.